# Connect single queue to multiple qmgrs C++

Tags: c++, queue, message-queue, ibm-mq

I want to **connect a single queue to multiple queue managers**
(atleast 2 qmgrs). Lets say I have `qmgrA and qmgrB` as queue managers and it is connected to `queueName`. I will put a message **"Hello"** to queueName connected to qmgrA as well as another message **"World"** on qmgrB. So suppose to be the queueName contains **"Hello"** and **"World"**.

The question is how can I get those messages simultaneously? Can you give me an example code fragment/snippet for me to atleast have an overview of how can I start coding with that design.

> **Note:** *I am asking for this because for example the `qmgrA` got  disconnected/down for unknown reason, atleast `qmgrB` is still active
>   and will get messages on `queueName` even though `qmgrA` is disconnected.
>
> By the way, I'm using Websphere MQ v7 C++.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

The question appears to be asking how to do something that IBM MQ does not do.  QMgrs do not "connect" to queues, they host them.  Applications do not "connect" to queues except in the abstract JMS sense.  They connect to QMgrs and then open queues.  However, the requirement that is described of keeping MQ highly available can be met with MQ Clusters, hardware clusters, Multi-Instance QMgrs, shared queues (on z/OS only), or some combination of these.

The two queue managers in your example each host a local copy of `queueName`.  Here are several scenarios as to how messages are distributed in this situation.

**`PUT`ting messages**

- A message put to `queueName` by an application connected to `qmgrA` will by default result in the message landing in the local instance of that queue.
- When there is a local instance and an MQ cluster with at least one other instance, the QMgr can be configured to allow messages to go to non-local instances.
- When `qmgrA`,  `qmgrB`, and  `qmgrC` are in a cluster, and `qmgrC` does not host a local instance of the queue, messages put to that queue name will round-robin between the instances on  `qmgrA` and  `qmgrB` .

**`GET`ting messages**

- A message landing in `queueName` on `qmgrA` can only be retrieved from that queue by an application connected to `qmgrA`.
- A message landing in `queueName` on `qmgrB` can only be retrieved from that queue by an application connected to `qmgrB`.
- An application connected to `qmgrC` cannot retrieved messages from the queues hosted on `qmgrA` or `qmgrB`.

**MQ HA**
The requirement to make a queue highly available can be achieved in several ways.  Some of these provide recoverability of the service provided by MQ.  Some of them provide recoverability of messages that would be stranded in-flight.  In addition to reading [topology design section](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pla.doc/q004720_.htm?lang=en) in the manuals, please see the [MQ HA presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/AndrewSchofield4/ame-2269-ibm-mq-high-availability) from IBM Interconnect 2015.

Comment: Hi @T.Rob, I got a rc code 2219, the design of the program is we have 2 threads. One for getting messages and one for putting/sending messages to the queue. So we got 2 processes running simultaneously.

**get** - will connect to queue manager, opens the queue and has a loop of getting messages indefinitely. (wait interval is set to unlimited, mqgmo_wait)

**put** - will connect to the same queue manager, opens the queue and will put messages to other queue.

We got an error on put while opening the queue with rc code 2219. Do you have any suggestion on how to address the rc code?

Comment: The main suggestion is that Stack Overflow doesn't work like a forum. It is a Q&A site.  Asking follow-up questions in the comments doesn't help anyone else find or benefit from them. Because this is not the intent, Stack Overflow makes it *very* hard to adequately answer questions in the comment section. I suggest opening up a new question.  If I don't see it and you want to direct me to it, my contact info is in my profile.  Email or Tweet to me with the link.

Comment: Also, you tend to get more enthusiastic responses in general by upvoting and accepting helpful answers.  Of your 8 questions, only one has been accepted.  All but one have answers, many of those answers have zero votes. I hope this advice helps make Stack Overflow more useful for you.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will post another question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does make very much sense.  Go look up MQ Clustering and MQ Multi-Instance in the MQ Knowledge Center. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q017820_.htm